# How to access Kotlin static method in Groovy Spock test

Tags: kotlin, groovy, mockito, spock, powermockito

I have kotlin class below

```kotlin
class DPCIValidator {

companion object {
     fun validate(value: String): Boolean {
        val regex = Regex(pattern = "\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d")
        return regex.matches(value)
     }
  }
}
```

Spock test below, I am unable to access Kotlin static method via spock

```
testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.2-M1-groovy-3.0'
```

```java
import spock.lang.Specification

class DPCIValidatorSpec extends Specification{

def 'test static method validate'(){
    when:
    Boolean test = DPCIValidator.validateDPCI("001-02-1234")

    then:
    assert test == true
}
```

Any help appreciated

Edit: updated spock test

Comment: This question seems to be completely unrelated to Spock or Groovy. You are not even using Spock mocks, but Mockito static mocks. Is it maybe rather a Kotlin question?

Comment: @kriegaex yes you are correct, I have updated test case now. below solution would work as per my requirement. you can explain me if there any better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but now you are not mocking anything anymore at all, but testing the real class. Hence, your original question does not make much sense anymore. BTW, the test code can be simplified to just `expect: DPCIValidator.validateDPCI("001-02-1234")`, no need to split into when-then, use explicit types or explicit `assert`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the @JvmStatic on your companion method.

See the following code :

```
class DPCIValidator {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun validate(value: String): Boolean {
        val regex = Regex(pattern = "\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d")
        return regex.matches(value)
    }
}
```

}

It specifies that a static method needs to be generated.

For more information see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/